# teradata stored procedure error writing into file

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I am having issue with replace or executing stored procedure in teradata. This error suddenly appears. The stored procedure I have created before does not work at all suddenly.

When I try to replace a procedure I am getting **Error 5547: failed to get the file size** and when try to execute an existing procedure I get **Error 7645: RTSExecSP: Error writing into file.** This procedure worked fine previously. I am using TD 15.00.02.06.

I have looked into the error definition for 7645 error in the TD site and it says that:

> "This error is reported when a problem is encountered while writing
>   into the stored procedure object code file or log files during SP or
>   DB spoil operations. This can occur when the directory has no space.
>   This is a system disk directory NOT part of the database."

Can anyone suggest me where in the TD OS I should look for this space?

here is a simple stored procedure I tried to compile

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MyDb].InsertSalary ( 
   IN in_EmployeeNo INTEGER, IN in_Gross INTEGER, 
   IN in_Deduction INTEGER, IN in_NetPay INTEGER

) 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO [MyDb].Salary ( 
      EmployeeNo, 
      Gross, 
      Deduction, 
      NetPay 
   ) 
   VALUES ( 
      :in_EmployeeNo, 
      :in_Gross, 
      :in_Deduction, 
      :in_NetPay 
   ); 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I faced same issue...I talked with my DBA...he made changes in permission level..it worked for me...